# $f: S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then there exists a point $x$ of $S^1$ such $f(x)=f(-x)$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

> Let $f: S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous map. Show there exists a point $x$ of $S^1$ such $f(x)=f(-x)$.

I could not understand what $-x$ means here?

I know that, $S^1=\{x\times y: \|x\times y\|=1\}$, where $x\times y\in\mathbb{R^2}$. I know the answer from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492599/f-s1-to-mathbb-r-is-continuous-then-fx-f-x-for-some-x-in-s1?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504138/fs1-rightarrow-r-continuous-means-there-exists-a-point-x-such-that-fx) links.

Comment: Hint: Use the function $g(x) = f(x)- f(-x)$. Note that $S^1 = \{(a, b)\in{\mathbb R}^2 : a^2+b^2=1\}$ and $-(a, b) = (-a, -b)$.

Comment: Remark that the result holds not only for the map $\phi(x) = -x$ in ${\mathbb S}^1$ but also for any continuous involution $\phi$ in a connected topological space $S$: there is a point $x$  such that $f(x) = f(\phi(x))$. For example in your case it would work for any symetry with respect to a line through the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb R^2$ is a vector space and $-x$ means opposite vector. If we use coordinates, $-(x,y) = (-x,-y)$ because $$(x,y)+(-x,-y) = (x+(-x),y+(-y)) = (0,0) = (-x+x,-y+y) = (-x,-y)+(x,y).$$

Also notice that $\|-x\| = \| x\|$ and hence, if $x\in\mathbb S^1$, then so is $-x$.

Comment: Where is the fact that $ f $ is continuous used?

Comment: @Jhöśë Elijäh, it is not used. In fact, $f$ is not used either. That's because OP asked a question different than what you probably think they asked.

Answer (score 1):

On $\Bbb S^1$ draw a line from $x\in \Bbb S^1$ to the origin in circle. continuing this line hit the circle on $-x$.

Comment: Aha! that is what I thinking. But needed to clarify. Thanks.