# For all $f: S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ exists point $x \in S^{n}$ such that $f(x) = f(-x)$

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve a topology problem. I know that spheres are non-contractible. I have also found something for [case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504138/fs1-rightarrow-r-continuous-means-there-exists-a-point-x-such-that-fx) $f: S^{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{}$. But how can I prove this for my case? Can anyone give me a hint?

> Prove that for all $f: S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ exists point $x \in S^{n}$ such $f(x) = f(-x)$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem

Comment: I hope you know that $f$ has to be continuous.

Comment: @KurtG. I know, thank you